# Remove special characters from dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can I remove special characters in columns in a dataframe. eg

| name | verified | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jason' Carly | True | 1 |
| Eunice, Banks | None | 2 |

Expected result

| name | verified | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jason Carly | True | 1 |
| Eunice Banks | None | 2 |

Comment: How do you define the special characters? Here spaces and English letters are not, what else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove everything that is not a space or an ASCII letter, use a regex:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z ]', '', regex=True)
```

output:

```
           name verified  id
0   Jason Carly     True   1
1  Eunice Banks     None   2
```